# How to make kafka replicate the source table structure in the destination table

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need some advise on how to make kafka replicate the source table structure in the destination table. Let me explain…

Source db: SQL Server
Source table :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PEOPLE(
    ID NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(10),
    LAST_NAME varchar(10),
    AGE NUMERIC(3)
)
```

Target db: PostgreSQL

Kafka sink connector:

```
name=pg-sink-connector_people

connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

tasks.max=4

topics=myserver.dbo.PEOPLE

connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/kafkadb

connection.user=postgres

connection.password=mypassword

insert.mode=upsert

pk.mode=record_key

pk.fields=ID

table.name.format=PEOPLE

auto.create=true

offset.storage.file.filename=C:/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/tmp/connect.offsets

bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

plugin.path=C:/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/plugins

transforms=flatten

transforms.flatten.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value

transforms.flatten.delimiter=_

auto.evolve=true
```

When I run the connector above, Kafka creates on PostgreSQL a target table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public."PEOPLE" (

    "before_ID" int8 NULL,

    “before_FIRST_NAME" text NULL,

    “before_LAST_NAME" text NULL,

    "before_AGE" int8 NULL,

    "after_ID" int8 NULL,

    "after_FIRST_NAME" text NULL,

    "after_LAST_NAME" text NULL,

    "after_AGE" int8 NULL,

    source_version text NOT NULL,

    source_connector text NOT NULL,

    source_name text NOT NULL,

    source_ts_ms int8 NOT NULL,

    source_snapshot text NULL DEFAULT 'false'::text,

    source_db text NOT NULL,

    source_schema text NOT NULL,

    source_table text NOT NULL,

    source_change_lsn text NULL,

    source_commit_lsn text NULL,

    source_event_serial_no int8 NULL,

    op text NOT NULL,

    ts_ms int8 NULL,

    transaction_id text NULL,

    transaction_total_order int8 NULL,

    transaction_data_collection_order int8 NULL,

    "ID" text NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "PEOPLE_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

The point is I don’t need these before/after fields or the others that were created. What’s the best way for replicating exactly the same structure of my source table?

Thanks!

Comment: One step would be to use a transform other than flatten. For example, I believe there's a whitelist one if you only need certain fields... Alternatively, if you're using Debezium, they have their own ExtractNewRecordState transform https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/event-flattening.html

Answer (score 2):

When you use Debezium it includes metadata about the change record that it's captured, as well as the before and after state. All this data comes through as a nested object.

At the moment you're just flattening all these fields with the `Flatten` Single Message Transform. If you don't want the additional fields you can use [the `ExtractNewRecordState` SMT](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/event-flattening.html) that's provided by Debezium for exactly this purpose. Use it **instead** of `Flatten`:

```
transforms=unwrap
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. According to my tests your suggestion works very well. The only remaining question is: what parameters should I use for deleting a row in my target table that has been previously deleted in the source one?

Comment: That's a different question - mark this one as answered (if you believe it is) and post a new one for your new question :)

Comment: add transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones=false  for deletion